# Angular JS $location.path() getter not updating

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I want to use the $location.path() method to return the URL path so I can write some conditional statements in an ng-hide directive. I created the following in my controller:

```
$scope.pathLocation = $location.path();
```

I then inserted {{pathLocation}} in my html just to make sure it was returning the correct path, which it is. The problem comes when I load a different view. The pathLocation doesn't update. If I manually refresh my browser on the new page view, it does. `

Here is an abbreviated version of my code:
Controller:

```
(function(){
  var amApp = angular.module('amApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies','ngAnimate' ]);

  amApp.controller('WelcomeController', ['$scope', '$location', function WelcomeController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.pathLocation = $location.path();
  }]);
})();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="amApp">
  <body ng-controller="WelcomeController as welcome">
    <nav>menu's here to different views in SPA</nav>
    {{pathLocation}}
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: How do you load different views? If you use `$location.path(newpath)` it should work, but if you're using any other method that only loads the view then you might need to set location too. (i.e. loading views is not equal to changing the location)

Comment: Why would you expect it to magically update when you're only assigning the value in one place? Sounds like you want to assign `pathLocation` on some event, maybe `$locationChangeSuccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, nothing in your code updates your `pathLocation` property. Try adding this

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.pathLocation = $location.path();
});
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. Yes, I was updating using an anchor tag and ng-href, so it wasn't updating. I misunderstood the documentation when it said that the path method automatically updated with a path change,

Answer (score 0):

Publish the function on scope:

```
amApp.controller('WelcomeController', ['$scope', '$location', function WelcomeController($scope, $location) {
    //$scope.pathLocation = $location.path();
    $scope.locationPathFn = $location.path;
}]);
```

Then execute the function in the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="amApp">
  <body ng-controller="WelcomeController as welcome">
    <nav>menu's here to different views in SPA</nav>
    {{locationPathFn()}}
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

Then on every digest cycle the `$location.path()` function will be checked and the view kept up to date.